# What does the Swedish princess say to the prime minister in Kingsman?

Tags: dialogue, kingsman-the-secret-service

Even if I am able to understand Norwegian, I barely understand what the (Norwegian) Swedish princess says to the prime minister in *Kingsman: The Secret Service*. Is there a transcript of her accusations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After having told Valentine "You are completely crazy," she turns to the prime minister and says

> Och när det gäller statsministern, (är jag) chockad över att du över huvud taget överväger det här. Du är vald av folket! Det är ditt jobb…

and then tries to get up from her chair before finishing her last sentence.

Translation:

> As for the prime minister, (I'm) shocked that you're even considering this. You're elected by the people! It's your job…

You never hear her say "är jag", but the sentence wouldn't make sense without it. This could be because in (at least) Standard Swedish or the Stockholm dialect (which it sounds like she's speaking) the two words are often compressed into a diphthong similar to /eɑ/, and could even become inaudible if the next word is emphasized enough. But if this is what she's doing, it's probably unintentional since she's otherwise trying to speak clearly in her role as royalty. Another explanation would be that it's simply removed during post-production, since it's missing just as they cut from showing the princess to showing the prime minister.

As she's getting up from her chair and leaving she again turns to the prime minister and says

> Det här är ju helt galet! Du kommer få ångra det här!

Translation:

> This is totally crazy! You'll regret this!

After having left the room, she yells

> Vakter! Hjälp!

Translation:

> Guards! Help!

I don't know what it sounds like to someone who doesn't understand Swedish, but I don't think she sounds that convincing. It's like the director just told her to say whatever in Swedish.

Answer (score 5):

It's the Norwegian prime minister and the Swedish princess, and she's talking Swedish, which norwegians can understand.

Edit the actor is Norwegian, but he might be playing the Swedish prime minister.

She's asking if he's totally crazy, and that he's elected by the people and he can't do this.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for that info... do you happen to know what is actually being said, though? That's what the question is asking.

Comment: How did I have the idea that she is norwegian? Strange... Thanks!

Comment: No, she tells Valentine (in English) that's he's crazy, and later on says (in Swedish) that this (i.e. the situation) is crazy. But she doesn't tell the prime minister that he's crazy, nor does she ask him whether he is.

Comment: @Catija I posted another answer with a transcript and translation.